# Angular 5: Can't resolve all parameters for Service

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently I picked up Angular 5 and I was tasked with creating somewhat of a demo-application.

Ng serve worked perfectly well and even ng build wasn't giving me any problems. I could constantly test if my application was working locally in development, but also on my local tomcat server (using XAMPP).

But when I wanted to use the production build, it went all downhill.

```
ERROR in : Can't resolve all parameters for DataService in C:/Users/ak/Documents/angular5_project/src/app/services/data.service.ts: (?, [object Object]).
```

I searched throughout several git repositories and other questions on stackoverflow for this.

At first, I thought I missed something basic.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { NotFoundError } from 'app/common/not-found-error';
import { BadInput } from 'app/common/bad-input';
import { AppError } from 'app/common/app-error';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  constructor(private url: string, private http: HttpClient ) {
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  get(id) {
    return this.http.get(this.url + '/' + id)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  create(resource) {
    //   return Observable.throw(new AppError());
    return this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify(resource))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  update(resource) {
    return this.http.put(this.url + '/' + resource.id,
      JSON.stringify(resource))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  delete(id) {
    return this.http.delete(this.url + '/' + id)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
    if (error.status === 404) {
      return Observable.throw(new NotFoundError());
    } else if (error.status === 400) {
      return Observable.throw(new BadInput(error.json()));
    } else {
      return Observable.throw(new AppError(error.json()));
    }
  }

}
```

But then I disregarded the more obvious choices, like forgetting the @Injectable annotation or forgetting to register the service as such in the app.module.ts

```
...
import { UserDataService } from 'app/services/user-data.service';
import { DataService } from 'app/services/data.service';
...
 providers: [
    MDBSpinningPreloader,
    AuthGuard,
    AdminAuthGuard,
    AuthService,
    UserDataService,
    DataService,
    EquipmentDataService,
    EquipmentAlarmDataService,
...
  ],
```

Often, the problem of circular dependencies is mentioned, but from what I have seen, it was never the basic service. I have several services that inherit from the DataService, like a user-service that simply returns a list of all available users from my Spring Backend (Just a set of Dummy Data):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'app/services/data.service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserDataService extends DataService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super('http://localhost:8080/users', http);

   }
}
```

Sadly, I didn't even get any warnings of circular dependency or anything remotely useful I could post here. Which means... nothing. The error message is my only source and I'm at my wit's end.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "quickstart-angular5",
  "version": "5.0.5",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:free": "ngm build -p src/app/typescripts/free --clean && gulp npmFree && gulp startFree && gulp onlyFree",
    "build:pro": "ngm build -p src/app/typescripts/pro --clean && gulp only-pro && gulp startPro",
    "build:all": "npm run build:free && npm run build:pro",
    "aot:build": "ng build --prod --sm=false --aot=true --output-path=dist",
    "pre-commit": "ng lint"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "chart.js": "2.5.x",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.x",
    "core-js": "2.4.x",
    "del": "3.0.x",
    "easy-pie-chart": "2.1.x",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.x",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.x",
    "gulp-run": "1.7.x",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.x",
    "ng-html-util": "1.0.x",
    "ngm-cli": "0.5.x",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "screenfull": "3.3.x",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "0.3.x",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.x",
    "zone.js": "0.8.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.6.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.85",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.5.0",
    "uglify-es": "3.3.8",
    "webpack": "3.x"
  }
}
```

EDIT: I've forgotten to mention, that I can do a general build. The productive build has aot-compilation true by default. When I deactivate it, it seemingly works, but the uglification seems to break as well and the page is broken. Triggering an error like this: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8391

My project only works if I use ng build only.

Comment: Remove DataService from providers because you inititialize it manually

Comment: It seems to have cleared up one problem, but created an avalanche of errors. Most of them simply popped up, because I don't have the appropriate value in the component.ts files in, so it's not too surprising they popped up during the production. I'll work on clearing them and tell ya if it worked! Thank you for advice so far!

Comment: I'm here after getting stuck in the example given in the tutorial by Mosh Hamedani. 
Removing ```@Injectable(){}``` code block did the trick.

Comment: @VibhorDube Avoid all his web-development tutorials like the plague. Most of them were already outdated by the time he released them. Worse, he never expends the effort to update them.

Comment: @ak.leimrey Sadly most of the students like me only come to know this after finishing almost 70-80% of the tutorial when the real functionality of the library starts and all the explained methods are deprecated that are shown in the video. :(

Comment: That's more of a downside to working with frameworks that change rapidly, its tough to keep video tutorials updated.

Comment: @RichFinelli Nah, even back then it was tragically off and wrong. The speed at which angular introduced breaking changes after version 4+ was relatively tame. The issue over the years - for me - with angular was poorly maintained external libraries. Thing is, Mosh was - regardless of Angular version - just incredibly wrong about almost everything he did. Looking back, as a pretty green developer I didn't challenge it as much, but looking back it was easily the worst Angular Tutorial to date.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your `DataService` service has two constructor parameters, `url` and `http`. `http` can be resolved because it is registered by the `HttpClientModule`, but the `url` parameter is not registered in the dependency injection container. That is the reason why you get the error.

I guess you always let inject a specific class, as for example `UserDataService`, into your components and never a `DataService` instance.

So you should refactor your `DataService` to an abstract `DataServiceBase` class and remove the `@Injectable()` decorator.

And as yurzui suggested, remove `DataService` from the list of providers.

Comment: You're right, I usually inject a specific service in my components. It worked by removing the DataService from the providers AND removing the Injectable annotation. I had skimmed the latter part ( a bad habit of mine) and saw the warning "This will become an error in Angular 6.x" and I realized I skipped the part of deleting the @Injectable. Now it does a productive build, but I can only try it out later if it actually works on my tomcat. However, the worst bit seems to be solved so far.
EDIT: I have a bit of trouble understanding exactly the issue with the url. Still a helpful response!

Comment: Angular dependency injection can only inject things which are registered before. When the DI container creates a new instance of the `DataService` class, it has to know the value of the `url` parameter. But you never defined what this value should be. The answer of Boris Lobanov shows a technic to register a string in the DI container with `useValue`. But you do not need this solution, because you never let create a `DataService` instance by the injector. See also https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: For my cause, this seems to be the most appropriate answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sometimes rebuilding the Angular app solves the problem, i.e. `ng serve`. This applies specially to cases with git when you pull new changes and a service created by a fellow programmer is created in the tree. Angular CLI's watch somehow misses to include the new service.

Answer (score 15):

The error indicates that the first argument in the constructor is causing the problem. And it should because it's a simple string. Try injecting it like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {

constructor(@Inject('API_BASE_URL') private url: string, private http: HttpClient) { // ... }
```

In your providers:

```
providers: [DataService, {provide: 'API_BASE_URL', useValue: 'http://localhost:8080/users'}]
```

Comment: I'm an below-average coder at best, I have to admit. Why is the first argument a problem? I mean, I figured it out eventually, since it's the one that is being referred to with a question mark, but I have still problems wrapping my mind around it. How does the Inject('API_BASE_URL') work in conjuction as a provider? Why is it necessary to have an injected value for something seemingly so simple like using an url? Don't get me wrong, though! Your response looks interesting and helpful enough, that I would like to try it out later. Your help is MUCH appreciated!

Comment: I think the official documentation on this matter is quite good and will explain it better than me: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#non-class-dependencies

Comment: Official docs are tough to follow without enough examples...

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly same error. I solved it by removing DataService from `providers: []` and also removing the `@Injectable` decorator from DataService.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps anyone, I had the same problem and it was because I had moved the @Injectable attribute off of the class that was unable to resolve any dependencies.

Where I had had

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService{}
```

I had added another POCO object to the file and placed it between the @Injectable and the service class definition.
That meant the POCO was now regarded as Injectable and the service no longer used the Dependency Injection framework.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and after 2-3 hours of struggle i realized that i  was creating instance of an interface in my constructor .for example :-

**constructor(
private readonly dataTable: DataTable,
) {}**

**Note**:- here DataTable is an interface .

Please check whether you are creating instance of an interface in your constructor , if yes then remove it .It worked for me .